# Octave: expecting scalar N, or 2-/4-element vector DOM-ezsurf Error

Tags: octave, surface

I need some kind of help about ezsurf
as I understand from my research matlab fplot is equal to ezplot in octave. And I write a script

```
fx = @(x,y) x.*sin(y);
fy = @(x,y) -x.*cos(y);
fz = @(x,y) y;
ezsurf(fx, fy, fz,[-5 5 -5 -2],'--','EdgeColor','g')
hold on
ezsurf(fx, fy, fz,[-5 5 -5 -2],'EdgeColor','none')
hold off
```

if I able to run the script I expect to see this image
[image: ezsuf]

However when I run the script I get this error

```
    error: ezsurf: expecting scalar N, or 2-/4-element vector DOM
error: called from
    __ezplot__ at line 260 column 7
    ezsurf at line 78 column 19
    file at line 4 column 1
```

What is the *"expecting scalar N"* what should I understand I how can I fix this.
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: remove the extra arguments `'--','EdgeColor','g'` and set them separately with set. Reading the help text of `ezsurf`, does look like it accepts setting properties for the actual surface.

Comment: also, please fill a bug report https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?func=additem&group=octave

Comment: Thank you so much, it works well, as I understand: I should not try to personalize the plot's color or minor shapes etc.

Comment: Usually it should be fine to personalize the plot's in such way but for some reason, Octave's `ezsurf` doesn't seem to allow it. It may be because it shouldn't work in Matlab either (Matlab documentation of `ezsurf` makes no mention of accepting any such options).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```matlab
fx = @ (x,y)  x .*sin(y);
fy = @ (x,y) -x .*cos(y);
fz = @ (x,y)  y;

h1 = ezsurf (fx, fy, fz, [-5, 5, -5, -2]);
set (h1, 'edgecolor', 'g', 'linestyle', '--', 'linewidth', 0.1);
hold on

h2 = ezsurf (fx, fy, fz, [5, -5, 5, -2]);
set (h2, 'edgecolor', 'none');
hold off

colormap (parula (256)); % assuming you have the parula colormap installed
```

[image]

Comment: wow, it works very well, thank you so much for your help, finally I got my personalized graph